# Why did Vision end up in Iron Man's team?

Tags: character, analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

Vision is a humanoid of pure logic. Also, he wishes not for the destruction of humanity like Ultron and is worthy enough to hold Thor's hammer.

Why does such being enter the Iron Man's team to force Avengers to obey UN's orders?

Shouldn't it be with Cap's team? Or at least stay neutral and do his best to avoid civil war?

* Bonus: Should we consider his lack of instinct/soul/empathy a factor for his actions, as opposed to Captain America for example?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61275/discussion-on-question-by-koita-pisw-sou-why-did-vision-end-up-in-iron-mans-tea).

Comment: Vision can move Thor's hammer the same way a Honda Civic could move Thor's hammer if Thor set it down in the front seat.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

TL;DR: It's specifically *because* he's a being of logic. Also, because of love.

First and foremost, it's important to remember Vision's original statement of loyalty from *Age of Ultron*. He is going to side with whichever group will protect life the best.

> CAPTAIN AMERICA: Are you? On our side?
>
> VISION: It's not that simple. (pause) I'm on the side of life. Ultron is not.

He explains that he sees logic in the oversight (all following quotes from [the Civil War transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War)):

> Vision: In the 8 years since Mr. Stark announced himself as Iron Man, the number of known enhanced persons has grown exponentially. And during the same period, the number of potentially world-ending events has risen at a commensurate rate.
>
> Steve Rogers: Are you saying it's our fault?
>
> Vision: I'm saying there may be a causality. Our very strength invites challenge. Challenge incites conflict. And conflict... breeds catastrophe. Oversight... **Oversight is not an idea that can be dismissed out of hand.**

He loves Wanda. Actor Paul Bettany confirms this in [an interview with EW](http://ew.com/article/2016/05/09/captain-america-civil-war-vision-paul-bettany-scarlet-witch/). Speaking of why he accidentally blasted Rhodey out of the sky, he says

> “**What happened there is that his judgment was clouded there by real love and affection**,” says Bettany. “And he responded in a quick and thoughtless way.… I really love that the moral compass of the movie is this synthetic person who’s trying to figure out what it means to be human. It’s a neat idea, you know?”

Because he loves Wanda, he believes that this is the best way to protect her.

> Tony Stark: If we don't do this now, it's gonna be done to us later. That's the fact. That won't be pretty.
>
> Wanda Maximoff: You're saying they'll come for me.
>
> Vision: We would protect you.

He truly believes that protecting Wanda from the public is also protecting the public.

> Wanda Maximoff: Vision, are you not letting me leave?
>
> Vision: [He blocks her way.] It is a question of safety.
>
> Wanda Maximoff: I can protect myself.
>
> Vision: [He holds her arm.] Not yours. Mr. Stark would like to avoid the possibility of another public incident. Until the Accords are on a... more secured foundation.
>
> Wanda Maximoff: And what do you want?
>
> Vision: For people to see you... as I do. [She looks at him gravely.]

and

> Vision: [He faulters.] If you do this... they will never stop being afraid of you.

So, he decides to go the utilitarian route: the greatest good for the greatest number:

> Vision: Captain Rogers. I know you believe what you're doing is right. But for the collective good you must surrender now. [Tony's team arrives.]

Of course, being that he is basing his allegiance on logic, he is willing to swap sides.

Actor Paul Bettany addressed this briefly in the interview mentioned earlier.

> “**He has logic in abundance. And logic does not afford any room for loyalty. New information could come to light and he might flip to Captain America’s side.** But love solidifies things and provides loyalty. So if he’s there to protect mankind – or frankly, the universe – he needs to figure out what’s good about these creatures, and I think that’s the quest that you find him on. And, of course, in the comics, the relationship becomes romantic. We’ll see moving forward what happens for Vision and Wanda.”

Comment: That's what I expected as an answer on question like this, +1

Comment: I think it's worth adding the caveat clearly somewhere that Vision being in love with Wanda is only a comic universe thing and the question is about (and tagged) the cinematic universe.

Comment: If you read the interview I linked, Paul Bettany - the actor who plays The Vision has said that The Vision loves Wanda in the MCU.

Comment: Never understood how Vision could be in love.

Comment: @TylerH it's pretty clear from the film that he has feelings for Wanda

Comment: @OrangeDog I disagree, at least to the extent of *romance*. It's clear he cares for her but it only comes off as paternal or familiar care, especially considering this is an android in mid-life adult form and what appears to be a teenage girl.

Comment: @phantom42 if there's a part of the interview where Bettany says Vision has romantic feelings for Wanda *in the movie*, you should include that section. The section you've included only shows Bettany saying Vision has romantic feelings/interactions with Wanda *in the comics*. Reading the interview now seems to only back this up. Further, Bettany even mentions his movie role is paternal in the interview. Even when speaking of love, its in general terms and about the whole team; at no point does he say that movie Vision has romantic love feelings for Wanda.

Comment: @TylerH we're talking about love, not specifically romance.

Comment: @OrangeDog No, phantom is specifically talking about romantic love: see above - "He is in love with Wanda,". Loving someone and being *in* love with them carry very different meanings.

Comment: @TylerH the kind of love has no impact on the actual question - why does he side with Tony?

Comment: @OrangeDog I agree, which is why it seems odd for phantom to inject a kind of love in the answer that doesn't exist in the movies. **Hence my comment.** This has been an attempt to improve the answer's quality by curtailing what is a bit liberal of a claim.

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy with work. I'll update the answer when I have time.

Comment: And no, he says that the relationship progresses to a romantic relationship in the comics - but that does not preclude him from loving her without there being a mutual romantic relationship. Love does not always mean romance.

Comment: As we saw with *Infinity War*, while it wasn't explicit in earlier movies, there  was absolutely a romantic component to their relationship.

Answer (score 15):

- You describe Vision as a being of pure logic. Logic is built on (unbreakable) rules. Exceptions to rules are, by definition, illogical to the rule. If Vision is placed based on his logical aptitude, I think he's in the right team already.
- Tony, while very flamboyant and extraverted, is a highly logical person. He is considerably more pragmatic than Cap; who goes with his gut more than Tony. It makes sense for Vision to agree with Tony, because they approach things the same way (analytically).
- Cap goes with his gut, and focuses more on "the human element". His stance is based on his tendency to **do good** more than being right or effective. This is an emotional stance, it is based on empathy more than logic. Almost in all media (even surpassing the MCU) that addresses differences between humans and machines, **empathy is THE skill that machines (and logical beings) archetypically lack**.

Three very good reasons why Vision picks the UN side of the debate, *if we assume he chooses logic above all else*.

However, it's not impossible that Vision is capable of making a "human" decision rather than a logical one; and that it is simply his opinion which causes him to pick Tony's side (just like how Tony's stance is an opinion).
Vision has shown to be able to have deep emotional talks; so it's not impossible for him to understand, acknowledge and even experience human emotions.

---

**Edit** - Another remark about what you say:

> [Vision] is worthy enough to hold Thor's hammer.

Take a step back, and look at who Thor is. Thor is the son of a **monarch**, which has ruled with an iron fist and very much controls the ins and outs of Asgard.

Thor is not someone who would fight for personal freedom **over** a controlling hand; as he is heir to the throne that controls Asgard.

Wielding Mjölnir does not in any way reflect on Vision's suggested stance in Civil War. And if it does, it would argue in favor of UN control; not against it.

Comment: Plus, he seems to "like" Wanda. Which add a lot to his emotional side.

Comment: @LeonFreire: Maybe you hadn't seen the edit yet, but I'm referring to Wanda when I say he's able to have deep emotional talks and understands (and possibly experiences) human emotion. That scene with Wanda is a very good indication that we should not consider Vision as a living machine, but rather a living creature in his own right. Not only was he capable of connecting with her; but he also understood why she betrayed him. That requires a considerable amount of empathy.

Comment: I think Vision is worthy of lifting Mjolnir in the same way an elevator is worthy. He is a machine performing some functions. He's not a living being so Odin's magic does not affect him.

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort: What about Iron Man? His suit moves via servomotors. The act of picking up Mjölnir is thererfore done by a machine (the suit). Therefore, Iron Man should be able to pick it up as well. What if Falcon is flying around and has a hook attached to the wings (which are robotic/mechanical)? Since Sam Wilson (the human) is not part of the "lifting" process (Mjölnir-hook-wingsuit), should Mjölnir allow itself to be picked up by a flying robot? Given that Mjölnir chooses who can pick it up, it stands to reason that Mjölnir decides (on the spot) what is appropriate and what is not.

Comment: @Flater Good questions. But Iron Man's servomotors are still ultimately decided by Tony himself, as is the case with Sam. With Vision it's the Mind gem that ultimately decides things, which is a magical artefact, but not a human mind. We can discuss the philosophical differences between a human brain and a computer but it's not the place for that. We're reading too much into these action movies already :P

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort: If you check the comment thread under the question itself, you will see a long discussion between me and LeonFreire on this topic. Following LeonFreire (and things I've looked up in the meanwhile), it is established that Mjölnir can be transported by robotic movement: elevators, vehicles, the Avengers' ship, ... All of these are under control of a (non-worthy) human, but they are still capable of transporting Mjölnir. So thererfore human control or intention does not preclude the moving of Mjölnir.